# Looking for a good Dynamic Imaging Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, resize, cdn

I work for a small E-Commerce shop and we are looking for a process that will handle resizing our product images dynamically.  Currently our designers take high resolution photos, either provided by the manufactures or created in house, and alter them to fit various pages on our site. The designers are constantly resizing, cropping, altering compression levels, etc., of each product photo to fit the needs of the business.  Being that our product line is updated frequently, this becomes a monotonous task.

Abobe Scene7 does exactly what we are looking to do and the images are served up from a CDN.  Unfortunately we found it to be too expensive.

I'm curious to learn how others handle this process at their organizations.  Does anyone know of any good 3rd party tools or other SAAS providers that can handle performing some basic image manipulation and serving them on the fly?

Answer (score 2):

A lot of what you describe can be accomplished using components available in the .NET framework.

We've used the COM version of [ImageGlue](http://www.websupergoo.com/imageglue-1.htm) with great success and found it to be very stable and effective. When someone uploads an image through our admin site, I use ImageGlue to generate a thumbnail and resize the image before storing it. You could also do that dynamically by having your image tags refer to a url like

```
<img src="/services/image?id=1231231&w=200&keepAspect=1">
```

and have the Image page or service generate the image and stream it back to the browser.

This doesn't address issues like content delivery networks, but it's relatively inexpensive and might get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The [ImageResizing.Net](http://imageresizing.net) library offers Amazon [CloudFront-compatible dynamic image resizing](http://imageresizing.net/plugins) - you get instantly resized dynamic images, and the scalability and responsiveness of edge caching.

While the core library is MIT-free, the [Cloud bundle](http://imageresizing.net) costs $99 (but includes source code and redistribution rights).

There isn't a hosted service version yet, but there may be soon. [Vote for the idea](http://resizer.uservoice.com/forums/108373-image-resizer-v3/suggestions/1876773-offer-an-imageresizing-service-based-on-amazon-s3) if you want it quicker.

-- The Author

Answer (score 1):

[Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com) is an IaaS solution for uploading images directly to the CDN, and crop, resize and transform uploaded images using URL commands:

https://uploadcare.com

For example, here is the full version of an image (which is quite heavy, 4034x2672px):

http://www.ucarecdn.com/6fdab0d5-5a07-4b34-8a3a-f61727972745/full.jpg

[image: Full version of an image]

And here is a cropped and resized one:

http://www.ucarecdn.com/6fdab0d5-5a07-4b34-8a3a-f61727972745/-/crop/1000x1000/1300,1600/-/resize/300x/tree.jpg

[image: Tree image]

More info: https://uploadcare.com/upload-api-cloud-storage-and-cdn/#crop-resize-and-transform-uploaded-images

Note: I am a co-founder :)

Answer (score 0):

Webqem is an Australian based company that offers a SAAS solution to dynamic imaging at a very competitive rate.

Check out the website at http://www.maxoom.com.au, there are a number of videos showing how functions within the service work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest has to be http://getthumbsup.com. We use it in conjunction with imgur sideloading feature http://api.imgur.com/resources_anon#sideloading flawlessly and effortlessly.